# Difference between Serial and USB devices on Linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb

I connected two MCU with Linux system one with serial interface and one with USB interface.Linux System recognize serial interface as ttys1 and USB interface as 28. For serial interface I can able to send and receive data via /dev/ttys1 device file. However for USB interface I am unable to send and receive data using /dev/usb/001/28 device file.

1. Why we can't access USB devices on Linux using specific device file same as with serial interface?
2. How we can send and receive data to and from connected USB devices?I already [read this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292933/how-can-i-write-raw-data-to-a-usb-device) its says we have to write code using libusb library.If so why we need that?

   ```
   For serial interface:
   echo -e "\0x20" > /dev/ttys1
   success

   For USB interface:
   echo -e "\0x20" > /dev/ttys1
   write error: Invalid argument
   ```

Comment: *"I connected two MCU with Linux system ... one with USB interface"* -- You need to be more specific than that.  Are you using a USB-serial adapter or a direct CDC ACM connection (i.e. the MCU is a USB gadget) or ???  *"However for USB interface ... /dev/usb/001/28 device file."* -- Not plausible; more likely `/dev/bus/usb/...`.   FYI `/dev/ttyS1` is not a *"serial device"* but a serial terminal.  You're trying to compare a serial terminal to a bus device.  Apples to oranges.  Your sample commands/results dialog looks bogus/repetative.

Comment: One MCU is using USB communication protocol while other one is using UART communication protocol for sending and receiving data to and from host devices(Linux PC).In linux all connected devicese treated as file thats why I just written file over there@sawdust

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files like `/dev/bus/usb/001/28` are created by the core USB driver in the Linux system (see [usb/core/devio.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/core/devio.c)).  This driver doesn't know anything about serial ports, it just knows about about USB.  So the commands you can send to this file are things like "read 32 bytes from endpoint 2" or "send 11 bytes to endpoint 3", and you would use a library like libusb or libusbp to send those commands.

However, I don't recommend doing that if you can achieve the same thing using the actual serial drivers, which create device nodes of the form `/dev/tty*` and also create symbolic links in `/dev/serial/by-id`.  You might be able to read and write from those devices using a shell like you were doing but I often find that it doesn't work the way I would expect.  You can use a serial terminal program like PuTTY or `screen` to send and receive ASCII bytes on a serial port (i.e. you type characters to send them).  You can also write a C program to [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) the port, set its serial port parameters using [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html), and then [read](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) from and [write](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) to it.

Comment: I am doing for testing purpose because this read and write operation will handle by application level.So how those guys will use that operation at application level.@David Grayson

Comment: I already gave three different suggestions of how to use serial ports (terminal program, shell commands like the ones in your question, and writing a C program that directly uses the standard serial APIs).  I don't understand why that information is not good enough for you; can you do a better job of explaining what exactly you are looking for? What do you mean by "application level"?  Whatever your application is, it can probably use the C program approach I described in my answer, or you can write the equivalent code in the language of your choice.

Comment: Ok got it so for serial port programming I have to use open ,read,write and termios system calls and for USB port I have to use that usb.c .thanks@David Grayson